# Rails: Issue assocating a record with a user who did not create that record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a single Users table with roles defined using enums in user.rb:

```
enum role: { staff: 0, clinician: 1 }
```

A staff user can create a patient record. That staff user who creates the patient record may be that patient's staff clinician, or they may not be, in which case I have a dropdown form that gives options for select of all stuff users. (The clinician user role is for outside clinicians - they are not involved)

I have a patients table in which I have user.id, which I intend to use to store the staff user id who created the patient, and staff_clinician_id, which I
intend to use to store the id of the patient's doctor (who will also be a staff user - confusing I know). Here's my patients schema:

```
  create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "age"
    t.integer  "staff_clinician_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.index ["staff_clinician_id"], name: "index_patients_on_staff_clinician_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_patients_on_user_id"

Then in my patients controller I've permitted staff_clinician_id and user_id:

    def patient_params
    params.require(:patient).permit(:age, :staff_clinician_id, :user_id, insurance_ids: [], gender_ids: [], concern_ids: [], race_ids: [])

end
```

and in the Patient model I've created this relationship:

```
has_one :staff_clinician, through: :users
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= select_tag "staff_clinician_id", options_from_collection_for_select(User.where(role:"staff"), "id", "name"), prompt: "Select this patient's clinician" %>
```

When I submit a new patient, the server says:

```
Started POST "/patients" for ::1 at 2017-09-25 14:16:44 -0400
Processing by PatientsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "patient"=>{"gender_ids"=>["1"], "race_ids"=>["1"], "insurance_ids"=>["1"], "concern_ids"=>["31"], "age"=>"243"}, "staff_clinician_id"=>"5", "commit"=>"Post"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["remember_token", "3e607ec61e623710c58c42a0d313395439f82a82"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Insurance Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "insurances".* FROM "insurances" WHERE "insurances"."id" = 1
  Gender Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "genders".* FROM "genders" WHERE "genders"."id" = 1
  Concern Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "concerns".* FROM "concerns" WHERE "concerns"."id" = 31
  Race Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "races".* FROM "races" WHERE "races"."id" = 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Gender Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "genders" WHERE "genders"."name" = ? AND ("genders"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["name", "Female"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Race Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "races" WHERE "races"."name" = ? AND ("races"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["name", "American Indian or Alaska Native"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "patients" ("created_at", "updated_at", "age", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", 2017-09-25 18:16:44 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-09-25 18:16:44 UTC], ["age", 243], ["user_id", 21]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "genders_patients" ("gender_id", "patient_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["gender_id", 1], ["patient_id", 7]]
  Gender Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "genders" WHERE "genders"."name" = ? AND ("genders"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["name", "Female"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "concerns_patients" ("concern_id", "patient_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["concern_id", 31], ["patient_id", 7]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "insurances_patients" ("insurance_id", "patient_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["insurance_id", 1], ["patient_id", 7]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "patients_races" ("race_id", "patient_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["race_id", 1], ["patient_id", 7]]
  Race Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "races" WHERE "races"."name" = ? AND ("races"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["name", "American Indian or Alaska Native"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (10.5ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/referral_requests/new?patient_id=7
Completed 302 Found in 172ms (ActiveRecord: 17.5ms)
```

but when I do Patient.last in console, it hasn't saved the staff_clinician_id. it is nil

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select tag should be named `patient[staff_clinician_id]`, not `staff_clinician_id`.

```
<%= select_tag "patient[staff_clinician_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(User.where(role:"staff"), "id", "name"), prompt: "Select this patient's clinician" %>
```

If you use the object-based form builder, you can use the shorthand:

```
<% form_for @patient do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.select :staff_clinician_id ... %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

`select` and `select_tag` are used in very different contexts.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Should I also be able to do something like Patient.last.staff_clinician with this implementation, or does that not work by design? I can do Patient.last.staff_clinician_id but not Patient.last.staff_clinician or Patient.last.staff_clinician.name which makes me think the relationship isn't configured correctly.

Comment: Right, it should just be `has_one :staff_clinician`, the `through` argument should not be necessary.

Comment: even though StaffClinician is not a model?

Comment: If it's not a model, you may need a class_name hint in the relationship declaration